# Cant view Sharepoint Online List Items with Visitor read permissions

Tags: list, permissions, read-only

Apologies for basic question, but im stumped! 
Ive granted site visitors read access but they cant see any items in any list. If i set the permissions to contribute/read then they can see the items.

I have:

- Created site with custom datasheetview list and added some items
- Granted site visitors Read permission at the site level
- Checked List permissions are same as site (Read for visitors)
- Checked List settings>Advanced>Item-Level Permissions are set to Read All Items
- Created another test list (after the read permissions were granted to visitors) and added some items with same settings as above.
- Checked the versioning settings are set to no content approval, no versioning and "any user with read can see draft items"
- Checked user is listed with read permissions in the Check Permissions
- Created a document library and uploaded a file, which the read only user can see and open fine

So documents seem ok but lists are not working as i would expect.

What am i missing here guys, this is driving me mad!

Comment: You can't view a list in datasheet view with read only permissions.  Are they able to view the items in a standard list view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design, users with read only permission can't get into a datasheet view because that is an edit operation, as evident when you up their permission to contribute.

Set the default view of the list to a standard view and they can see the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't view a list in datasheet view with read only permissions. Are they able to view the items in a standard list view? – Nate 12 mins ago